# Data Explorer &amp; The Encoding Trouble

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, encoding

This isn't, surprisingly, another double-encoding bug - it's a not-enough-encoding bug. The Data Explorer doesn't like the question [Do I really need to encode '&' as ' &amp;'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493405).

Question title screenshot:

> [image: Question, containing "&amp;" in title]

Data Explorer results:

> [image: Data Explorer rendering it as "&"]

Additional testing has revealed that [jQuery: how to add <li> in an existing <ul>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145208) and [How do I translate a &#174; into Silverlight Text Represenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715260) have their titles encoded properly - so it's just `&amp;` that trips it up. What gives?

---

**Edit:** [This very question is a useful test case.](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/127527/post-data-viewer?PostId=192224)

Comment: The space in that question title bothers me.

Comment: Is this a security vuln?

Comment: @ColeJohnson No.

Comment: @TimStone darn.

Comment: @Ben nothing was done, the Data Explorer revision is "rev 2013.8.7.10" and the [bug still exists](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lUjU3.png). Why status-completed?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Maybe the pull request got "dispositioned", and it's just caching or something biting again. (I don't know what half this version-control jargon means.)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: the [pull request was accepted](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/13#ref-commit-70a7d14), and that's why I marked it completed.  SEDE just hasn't been built in about a month.  I'll get it built out today.

Comment: @Ben thought those two actions are intertwined somehow, anyway last time it took over a year for SEDE to be built, lol!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this was meant to be a feature so that the already-escaped entities in post body contents would be displayed as they were originally written, but since that field shows you the rendered HTML otherwise I'm not sure that that makes much sense.

I've gone ahead and [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/13) that's less picky about which ampersands it encodes as `&amp;`, so this should be fixed in the next deploy after that change is pulled.

Comment: Once the pull request is dispositioned, I (or @NickCraver) can [tag:status-completed] or [tag:status-declined] this.